# How to automatically call a text file with today's date in Python

Tags: python, datetime, import, text-files

I have a text file that is generated everyday and is named in the following format: "year-month-date.txt" (e.g. 2016-08-25.txt).

Now I would like to open the text file with python and read some data from it. But I would like to do this without manually changing the name of text file inside the code everytime (remember the name of text file changes everyday).

So far I have (line 6 is is the part that needs fixing):

```
#1 Get today's date
import datetime
todays_date=datetime.date.today()
print(todays_date)
#2 Import info from a text file that is named as today's date
filename=todays_date.txt
fin=open(filename,'r')
Line1list=fin.readline()
print(Line1list)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to extract a string in the correct format from `todays_date`.

Use `strftime` for that (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```
filename = todays_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.txt'
```

Full example:

```
import datetime

todays_date = datetime.date.today()
filename = todays_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.txt'
print(filename)
>> 2016-08-25.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

filename should be a string, you are now trying to access the attribut .txt of todays date...

replace by:

```
todays_date=datetime.date.today()

filename = str(todays_date)+'.txt'
```

Also make sure that todays_date exactly matches the name of the txt file, you may need to shuffle the days, months and years. The above only works if the file is indeed something like '2016-08-25.txt'

Comment: That won't work as expected. `str(datetime.now())` returns a string in the "wrong" format.

Comment: sorry but when i test this it returns the exact format that the poster asks for. also the original code refers to:  datetime.date.today() not datetime.now()

Comment: You are correct, I missed the fact that OP is using `datetime.date.today()` rather than `datetime.now()`.